# add new property id to google analytics tracking in Android app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-analytics

I created a new property id for an android app.

(it's a Cordova project)

I changed it to the new track id in analytics.xml.

```
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXX-2</string>
```

Then build the project and play around with it. When I checked in GA Real-time view, there has no activity at all.

in iOS version, it's working fine when I changed to new tracking id, I saw it's trying to get my new real-time activities, but for android version, it doesn't work.

I checked in the log, I saw this error message:

```
12-04 15:42:38.389: W/GAV2(11143): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), using local store.
```

just wondering if I need to change other files?

Comment: Service unable error comes generally when service is down.

Comment: But iOS version is working fine for me.

Comment: Can you post your manifest file.